# How can i integrate payU with Node.js?

Tags: node.js, payu

I am new to **Node.js.** I am working on a stuff that to **integerate payU payment** **gateway with Node.js**. I have spent my whole day in analysing npm registry for a proper module. I have got only payu as a module with some list of API. I was searching some working example for my detailed study to do my stuff. But I didn't get any clear idea. If any one can guide me please help me.

**Thanks in Advance!!**

Comment: What part u explored and implemented?

Answer (score 0):

Trexle is a commercial service that lets you [integrate payubiz with nodejs](https://trexle.com/integrations/payubiz/nodejs) and other platforms. I believe this should be the right answer to the question since the only answer only reference a 3rd party site, and the OP never asked for a free resource.